# Returning values to a Python script 1 from python script 2 which was called by script 1 itself

Tags: python

I have one python script `GenXML.py` which generates an XML using ElementTree, After creating the XML, I want to pass that xml to another python script `parXML.py` from `GenXML.py` itself.

In the `parXML.py`, I am parsing the xml and reading one of the tag values, i want to return this value to the calling script `GenXML.py`.

How to achieve this please?

I tried `X=os.system("parXML.py op.xml")` and `X=subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "test.py", "op.xml"])` but couldn't work that out.

For the test purposes..i used simple example as :

val3 = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "test.py", "10"]) in GenXML.py and

test.py is

import sys
def main(arg):
print arg

if **name** == "**main**":
main(sys.argv[1])

However, i am not getting 10 in Val3 as expected

Comment: You can import parXML.py directly (`import parXML`) inside of GenXML.py ?

Comment: I can try that out or even create a similar class in GenXML.py as well but there are a lot more things involved as the data for tags is coming from server via django so  first want to explore possibilities of keeping the two files separate

Comment: You can `print()` the required result inside of parXML.py and then use `subprocess.check_output()`. The prints from parXML.py will be returned as stdout from `subprocess.check_output()`

Comment: can i capture that stdout in to a variable in the callling script, i am doing that but it fails with called process error. For a simple test i am using :

val3 = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "test.py"]) (jn the calling script)

import sys
def main(arg):
    print arg

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])   (in the called script)

Comment: Can you add the full error message as part of your question ?

Comment: I am passing that value to the front end and the error is :

CalledProcessError at /cal
Command '['C:\\Users\\Ashu\\Envs\\test\\Scripts\\python.exe', 'test.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cal
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Value: 
Command '['C:\\Users\\Ashu\\Envs\\test\\Scripts\\python.exe', 'test.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
Exception Location: c:\users\ashu\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py in run, line 512
Python Executable: C:\Users\Ashu\Envs\test\Scripts\python.exe

Comment: You can edit your question and copy-paste the error message there (it's more readable).

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824461/python-subprocess-calledprocesserror-returned-non-zero-exit-status-2